# How can I clear the channel history in Slack?

Tags: slack

How can I clear the channel history?

The channel in question is a private channel created by me and is not (yet) archived.

Comment: If you're a developer, you can find more advanced options here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32824336/247696

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to batch delete messages through [the Slack archives page](https://my.slack.com/archives), but this only lets you delete one page of messages at a time and does not delete any corresponding file uploads.

A better solution that deletes all messages from channels and/or groups, including file attachments, is this Python library: [`slack-cleaner2`](https://github.com/sgratzl/slack_cleaner2) (this replaces the deprecated [`slack-cleaner`](https://github.com/kfei/slack-cleaner)). You'll need to be familiar with the programming language Python to use it.

Comment: A modern version: [sgratzl/slack_cleaner2: Python3 module for deleting Slack messages and files using the Slack REST API](https://github.com/sgratzl/slack_cleaner2)

Comment: The link to the Slack archives page doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

**A very fast way to do this is to recreate the channel**:

1. Open your channel in Slack
2. Click the config button and choose "**Additional Options**"
3. Choose "**Rename the Channel**" and name it something (like "old-channel")
4. Create a new channel with the same name as the original

In my case, I archived the old channel afterwards.

Comment: Not valid for #general channel. You can not delete it or eliminate people from that channel

Answer (score 2):

Now, we can set a private channel or direct message retention policy on Slack.

For example, if you set a retention policy of one day, all messages in the channel or direct message will be deleted after one day.

FYI: [Set-private-channel-and-direct-message-retention-policies](https://slack.com/intl/en-hk/help/articles/115005393586-Set-private-channel-and-direct-message-retention-policies)

Comment: You need to be on a paid plan to have a retention policy.